# Is it a good practice to use alternate exchange in RabbitMQ as dead letter exchange?

Tags: rabbitmq, middleware, rabbitmq-exchange

I know that RabbitMQ has alternative and dead letter exchange types.

Since we don't have mapped queues for some message, from my perspective it is some kind of problem when we don't know what the message is. In this case we use alternative exchange to rout the message to another exchange by default (that can solve our routing problem).

Is it a good practise to use alternative exchange as dead letter exchange simultaneously?